# What is the behavior of super() and __init__() in class inherited from object?

Tags: python, inheritance, language-implementation

Using python 2.7 with new class style, if my class inherits from `Object`class, what is the behavior of `super(ClassName, self).__init__()` ? What I mean is, what happens behind the scenes ? What is the difference if I omitted it ?

An example above:

```
  class ClassName(object):
    """docstring for ClassName"""
    def __init__(self, arg):
        super(ClassName, self).__init__() ## The question above is about this super
        self.arg = arg


  class OtherClass(ClassName):
    """docstring for OtherClass"""
    def __init__(self, arg, otherArg):
        super(OtherClass, self).__init__(arg) ## The question below is about this super
        self.otherArg = otherArg
```

If I omit the `super`, what is the happens behind the scenes ?

Thanks.

Comment: Note that the call to `super` in `OtherClass` is not safe, since there is no guaranteed that the next class in the MRO allows an argument to `__init__` (e.g., since it might be `object`).

Answer (score 1):

In the case of single inheritance, absolutely nothing. `object.__init__()` does squat.

In the case of [multiple inheritance](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#multiple-inheritance), one entire [chain of initialization](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/) is not called. What this does to your application varies, but it's generally not a good thing to happen.